# Java-Spring Reflection brings method which are not present in the class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, reflection

I try to investigate classes available in a given package. for time being i have hard coded the class name, `I get so many methods which are not available in the class when i try to print all the methods and parameter type the method takes`

the following is my main class where i investigate the class and its method :

```
package com.hexgen.reflection;

`// removed imports to post question`
import com.hexgen.tools.HexgenClassUtils;

public class HexgenWebAPITest {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked", "unused" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HexgenWebAPITest test = new HexgenWebAPITest();
        HexgenClassUtils hexgenClassUtils = new HexgenClassUtils();
        String uri="";
        String[] mappingValues=null;
        HttpClientRequests httpRequest = new HttpClientRequests();
        Class parames = CreateRequisitionRO[].class;

        Class booleanVal;
        booleanVal = Boolean.TYPE;
        Class cls;


        try {
            List classNames = hexgenClassUtils.findMyTypes("com.hexgen.*");
            Iterator<Class> it = classNames.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext())
            {

                Class obj = it.next(); 
                System.out.println("Methods available in : "+obj.getName());
                System.out.println("===================================");
                if(obj.getName().equals("com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI")){
                    cls = Class.forName(obj.getName());
                    cls.getClass();
                    Method[] method = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
                    int i=1;
                    for (Method method2 : method) {
                        System.out.println(+i+":"+method2.getName());
                        Class[] parameterTypes = method2.getParameterTypes();
                        for (Class class1 : parameterTypes) {
                            System.out.println("Parameter Type : "+class1.getName());
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

this is the `Utility Class`

```
package com.hexgen.tools;
```

`// removed imports to post the question here`

```
public class HexgenClassUtils {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes"})
    public List<Class> findMyTypes(String basePackage) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory = new CachingMetadataReaderFactory(resourcePatternResolver);

        List<Class> candidates = new ArrayList<Class>();
        String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX +
                                   resolveBasePackage(basePackage) + "/" + "**/*.class";
        Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(packageSearchPath);
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            if (resource.isReadable()) {
                MetadataReader metadataReader = metadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(resource);
                if (isCandidate(metadataReader)) {
                    candidates.add(Class.forName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName()));
                }
            }
        }
        return candidates;
    }
    public String resolveBasePackage(String basePackage) {
        return ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath(SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(basePackage));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public boolean isCandidate(MetadataReader metadataReader) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName());
            if (!c.isInterface() && c.getAnnotation(Controller.class) != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable e){
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and this is the actual class which i am investigating:

```
package com.hexgen.api.facade;

`// removed imports to post question here`

import com.hexgen.datauploader.ETLServiceProvider;


import com.hexgen.ro.response.UserDetailsResponse;

/**
 * Hexagon Global IT Services (ALL RIGHTS RESERVED) Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: mayankk Date: 23/11/12 Time: 10:27 AM To change this template use File
 * | Settings | File Templates.
 */
@Controller
@Transactional
public class HexgenWebAPI {

    @Resource(name = "facadeDbFuncs")
    private DbFuncs dbFuncs;

    @Resource(name = "gatekeeper")
    private IGateKeeper gateKeeper;

    @Resource(name = "userContext")
    private UserContext userContext;

    @Resource(name = "costCalc")
    private FinancialCalculator financialCalculator;

    @Resource(name = "ytmCalc")
    private YTMCalculator ytmCalc;

    @Resource(name = "etlService")
    private ETLServiceProvider etlService;

    @Resource(name = "biManager")
    private IBIManager biManager;

    private String tmpFileName;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HexgenWebAPI.class);

    private Pattern c4Pattern;

    public HexgenWebAPI() {
        String cmdPattern = "([bsBS])[ ]+(\\w+)[ ]+(\\d+)[ ]*@[ ]*(\\d+\\.?\\d*)";
        c4Pattern = Pattern.compile(cmdPattern);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/user/details")
    public @ResponseBody
    UserDetailsResponse getLoggedinUserDetails() {
        HexGenUser details = (HexGenUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        populateImplementationDetails(response);
        return response;
    }

    private void populateImplementationDetails(UserDetailsResponse response) {
        logger.debug("Finding revision details");
        try {
            CodeSource codeSource = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain()
                    .getCodeSource();
            if (codeSource != null) {
                JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(codeSource
                        .getLocation().openStream());
                Manifest manifest = jarStream.getManifest();
                logger.debug("Manifest not found!");
                if (manifest != null) {

                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
        logger.debug("Could not find revision details, seems like development environment.");
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_REQUISITION')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.debug("Starting createRequisition()...");
        for (int i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
            CreateRequisitionRO requisitionRequest = request[i];


        {
            logger.debug("Record is for update ? {}", mr.isUpdate());
            logger.debug("attrs are {}", mr.getChangedRecord());
        }
        gateKeeper.route(request);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_ORDER')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createorder")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createOrder(@RequestBody CreateOrderRO request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {

        TradeDtl orderRow = dbFuncs.references.tradeDtl.findByTransId(request
                .getTransRef());
        d


        logger.debug("Starting createOrder()...");
        gateKeeper.route(request);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/confirmorder")
    public @ResponseBody
    void confirmOrder(@RequestBody ConfirmOrderRO request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {



        logger.debug("Starting confirmOrder()...");
        gateKeeper.route(request);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/trade/review/approve")
    public @ResponseBody
    void approveReview(@RequestBody ApproveReviewRO request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.trace("approveReview({},{})", request, validateOnly);
        gateKeeper.route(request);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/trade/review/reject")
    public @ResponseBody
    void rejectReview(@RequestBody RejectReviewRO request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.trace("HexgenWebAPI.rejectReview({},{})", request, validateOnly);
        gateKeeper.route(request);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/upload/overwrite/approve")
    public @ResponseBody
    void approveUpload(@RequestBody ApproveReviewRO request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.trace("approveUpload({},{})", request, validateOnly);
        UploadJobMaster uploadJobMaster = dbFuncs.references.uploadJobMaster.findOne(request.getId());
        AbstractUploadOverwriteRO uploadAcceptRO = null;
        Class<?> loaderRO = null;
        try {
            String className = etlService.getOverwriteAcceptEventName(uploadJobMaster.getUploadGenericType());
            loaderRO = Class.forName(className);
            uploadAcceptRO = (AbstractUploadOverwriteRO) loaderRO.newInstance();
            uploadAcceptRO.setUploadID(uploadJobMaster.getUploadId());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        gateKeeper.route((IRO) uploadAcceptRO);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/upload/overwrite/reject")
    public @ResponseBody
    void rejectUpload(@RequestBody RejectReviewRO request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {

        try {
            String className = etlService.getOverwriteRejectEventName(uploadJobMaster.getUploadGenericType());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        gateKeeper.route((IRO) uploadRejectRO);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload/file")
    public @ResponseBody
    FileUploadResponse upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        FileUploadResponse fileUploadResponse = new FileUploadResponse();

        try {
            file.transferTo(tmpFile);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fileUploadResponse.setStatusMessage("passed");
        return fileUploadResponse;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}")
    public @ResponseBody
    void uploadForm(@PathVariable String uploadType,
            @PathVariable String uploadName) {
        FileReceivedForUploadRO requisitionRequest = new FileReceivedForUploadRO(

        gateKeeper.route(requisitionRequest);
    }

    //Reports
    @PostFilter("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(null, 'REPG' + filterObject.groupId)")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/reports/groups")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<ReportsGroups> RetrieveReportGroups() {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        return biManager.getReportGroups();
    }

    @PostFilter("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(null, 'REPN' + filterObject.reportId)")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/reports/list")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<ReportNames> RetrieveReports(@RequestParam("groupId") BigDecimal groupId) {
        return biManager.getReportNames(groupId);
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(null, 'REPN' + #reportId)")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/reports/fields")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<FilterParameters> RetrieveReportFields(@RequestParam("reportId") BigDecimal reportId) {
        ReportGroupMapping report = dbFuncs.references.reportGroupMapping.findOne(reportId);
        return biManager.getFilterParameters(report.getReportName());
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(null, 'REPN' + #request.reportId)")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/reports/generateurl")
    public @ResponseBody
    GenerateURLResponse generateURL(@RequestBody GenerateURLRO request) { 
        ReportGroupMapping report = dbFuncs.references.reportGroupMapping.findOne(request.getReportId());
        try {
            return new GenerateURLResponse(biManager.generateURL(report.getReportName(), request.getReportParameters()));
        } catch(BOValidationException e) {
            throw new ValidationException(e.getViolations());
        }
    }

    // TODO throw away code
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload/eodprocess")
    public @ResponseBody
    void dayChange() {
        DayChangeRO dayChangeRO = new DayChangeRO();
        gateKeeper.route(dayChangeRO);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/overview/holdings")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<HoldingsRO> generateHoldingsReport() {
        List<HoldingsQO> holdingsQO = dbFuncs.references.reportsMgrFinders
                .getAllHoldings();


            holdingsRO.add(new HoldingsRO(holding.getAssetClass(), holding
                    .getUnRealTcy(), holding.getUnRealPcy()));
        }

        return holdingsRO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/overview/funds")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<FundOverviewRO> generatePortfolioTrend() {
        List<FundOverviewQO> fundOverviewQO = dbFuncs.references.reportsMgrFinders
                .getPortfolioMovement();

        List<FundOverviewRO> fundOverviewRO = new ArrayList<FundOverviewRO>();
        .getLast30Day()));
        }

        return fundOverviewRO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/fund/holdings/{portfolio}")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<HoldingsRO> generateHoldingsReport(@PathVariable String portfolio) {
        List<HoldingsQO> holdingsQO = dbFuncs.references.reportsMgrFinders
                .getFundHoldings(portfolio);

        List<HoldingsRO> holdingsRO = new ArrayList<HoldingsRO>();
        for (HoldingsQO holding : holdingsQO) {
            String securityDescription = holding.getSecurityDescription()
                    .substring(
                            0,
                            Math.min(holding.getSecurityDescription().length(),
                                    20));
            holdingsRO.add(new HoldingsRO(holding.getAssetClass(), holding
                    .getAccrIntTcy(), holding.getAodTcy(), holding
                    .getUnRealTcy(), holding.getUnRealPcy()));
        }

        return holdingsRO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/fund/concentration/{portfolio}")
    public @ResponseBody
    ConcentrationRO[] getConcentrationForFund(@PathVariable String portfolio) {
        List<ConcentrationRO> concentrations = new ArrayList<ConcentrationRO>();

        concentrations
                .add(generateConcentrationRO(dbFuncs.references.concentrationFinders
                        .getAssetGroupExposureFor(userContext.getCompany(),
                                portfolio)));
        concentrations
                .add(generateConcentrationRO(dbFuncs.references.concentrationFinders
                        .getAssetClassExposureFor(userContext.getCompany(),
                                portfolio)));
        concentrations
                .add(generateConcentrationRO(dbFuncs.references.concentrationFinders
                        .getIndustryExposureFor(userContext.getCompany(),
                                portfolio, "IND")));

        return concentrations
                .toArray(new ConcentrationRO[concentrations.size()]);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/overview/concentration")
    public @ResponseBody
    ConcentrationRO[] getConcentrationForFund() {
        List<ConcentrationRO> concentrations = new ArrayList<ConcentrationRO>();

        concentrations
                .add(generateConcentrationRO(dbFuncs.references.concentrationFinders
                        .getAssetGroupExposureFor(userContext.getCompany())));
        concentrations
                .add(generateConcentrationRO(dbFuncs.references.concentrationFinders
                        .getAssetClassExposureFor(userContext.getCompany())));
        concentrations
                .add(generateConcentrationRO(dbFuncs.references.concentrationFinders
                        .getIndustryExposureFor(userContext.getCompany(), "IND")));

        return concentrations
                .toArray(new ConcentrationRO[concentrations.size()]);
    }

    public ConcentrationRO generateConcentrationRO(
            ConcentrationFinders concentrationFinder) {
        ConcentrationRO concentrationRO = new ConcentrationRO();



        for (ValueQO valueQO : concentrationFinder.getValues()) {
            concentrationRO.addValue(valueQO.getName(), valueQO.getActual(),
                    valueQO.getGuidance());
        }

        return concentrationRO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/c4/execute")
    public @ResponseBody
    void executeC4Command(@RequestBody C4CommandRO request) {

        logger.debug("Received command for execution : " + request.getCmd());

        try {

            Matcher matcher = c4Pattern.matcher(request.getCmd());
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String parsedTransCode = matcher.group(1);

            } else {
                logger.debug("Invalid C4 command");
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.debug("Ooops !! C4 command execution failed - "
                    + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    // FIXME C4 throw away code
    private void createRequisitionThroughC4(String security, String transCode,
            BigDecimal price, BigDecimal quantity) {

        logger.debug("Starting createRequisition() through C4...");

        try {


            Security securityRow = dbFuncs.references.security
                    .findBySecurity(security);

            if (securityRow.getIsIntApplic() || securityRow.getIsDiscounted()) {
                createRequisition.setYtm(ytmCalc.computeXIRR(security, price,
                        userContext.getBusinessDate()));
            } else {
                createRequisition.setYtm(BigDecimal.ZERO);
            }

            SystemDefault defaults = dbFuncs.references.systemDefault
                    .findByParamLevelAndCompanyAndDivisionAndPortfolio(
                            ParamLevel.PF, userContext.getCompany(),
                            userContext.getDivision(), portfolio);

            OutputValuesFromInvestmentsDO response = financialCalculator
                    .costSettlementCalculator(input);

            createRequisition.setTransSrlNo(BigDecimal.ONE);
            if (transCode.equals("BUY")) {
                createRequisition.setInflowOutflow(InflowOutflow.I);
            } else {
                createRequisition.setInflowOutflow(InflowOutflow.O);
            }
            createRequisition.setFundManager(createRequisition.getUserId());
            createRequisition.setCustodianN(defaults.getCustodianN());

            gateKeeper.route(createRequisition);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.debug("Ooops !! C4 command execution failed - "
                    + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

but the folloing is the out put i get where i see many methods are not present in the class :

```
1:ajc$get$validator
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
2:ajc$set$validator
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : javax.validation.Validator
3:ajc$get$requestToEventTranslator
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
4:ajc$set$requestToEventTranslator
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.p0.translator.RequestToEventTranslator
5:ajc$interMethodDispatch2$com_hexgen_api_facade_HexgenWebAPIValidation$validate
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
6:handleValidationException
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.ValidationException
7:createRequisition
Parameter Type : [Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;
Parameter Type : boolean
8:getLoggedinUserDetails
9:populateImplementationDetails
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.response.UserDetailsResponse
10:excelMDM
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.MdmFromExcelRO
11:createOrder
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateOrderRO
Parameter Type : boolean
12:confirmOrder
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ConfirmOrderRO
Parameter Type : boolean
13:approveReview
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ApproveReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
14:rejectReview
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.RejectReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
15:approveUpload
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ApproveReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
16:rejectUpload
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.RejectReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
17:upload
Parameter Type : org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
18:uploadForm
Parameter Type : java.lang.String
Parameter Type : java.lang.String
19:RetrieveReportGroups
20:RetrieveReports
Parameter Type : java.math.BigDecimal
21:RetrieveReportFields
Parameter Type : java.math.BigDecimal
22:generateURL
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.GenerateURLRO
23:dayChange
24:generateHoldingsReport
25:generateHoldingsReport
Parameter Type : java.lang.String
26:generatePortfolioTrend
27:getConcentrationForFund
Parameter Type : java.lang.String
28:getConcentrationForFund
29:generateConcentrationRO
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.core.orm.finders.repositories.ConcentrationFinders
30:executeC4Command
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.C4CommandRO
31:createRequisitionThroughC4
Parameter Type : java.lang.String
Parameter Type : java.lang.String
Parameter Type : java.math.BigDecimal
Parameter Type : java.math.BigDecimal
32:createRequisition_aroundBody0
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : [Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;
Parameter Type : boolean
33:createRequisition_aroundBody1$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : [Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : [Lcom.hexgen.ro.IRO;
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
34:createOrder_aroundBody2
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateOrderRO
Parameter Type : boolean
35:createOrder_aroundBody3$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateOrderRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
36:confirmOrder_aroundBody4
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ConfirmOrderRO
Parameter Type : boolean
37:confirmOrder_aroundBody5$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ConfirmOrderRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
38:approveReview_aroundBody6
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ApproveReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
39:approveReview_aroundBody7$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ApproveReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
40:rejectReview_aroundBody8
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.RejectReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
41:rejectReview_aroundBody9$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.RejectReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
42:approveUpload_aroundBody10
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ApproveReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
43:approveUpload_aroundBody11$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.ApproveReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
44:rejectUpload_aroundBody12
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.RejectReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
45:rejectUpload_aroundBody13$advice
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.request.RejectReviewRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPIValidation
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.ro.IRO
Parameter Type : boolean
Parameter Type : com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI
Parameter Type : org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
46:ajc$preClinit
```

Comment: i have removed few implementation code as well as imports since i am not able to post them here for length violation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different parts of the Spring frame-work perform instrumentation at run-time to, to augment classes and provide additional functionality. Spring uses three different kinds of instrumentation:

- DynamicProxies - this is a feature of J2SE, and allows generating an interface "on-the-fly" by specifying "method handlers" - a method that gets called to handle method invocations. The handler will look at the method signature and arguments to decide what to do. Typically this will involve adding dome functionality before or after calling a the corresponding method on a concrete target class that implements the same interface. (Hence the name 'proxy'). Dynamic Proxies are the default when a class is backed by an interface.
- Byte-code-engineering (BCEL). This involves overriding the class-loader method that loads a class the first time it is required. The overridden method returns a sub-class that is generated at runtime, and includes extra functionality. The library that Spring uses this is 'cglib' which is built on top of 'asm'. . . These libraries prioritize performance over ease-of-use. . . (ease of use not being a concern, since the Spring user doesn't do any byte-code engineering for themselves - just uses the instrumented classes).
- AspectJ weaving. This involves using either compile-time weaving or runtime weaving. In the case of the latter a special Java Agent is used (cmd-line argument to the JVM) instead of intercepting the classloader.

Examples of instrumentation are annotation-based transactions, security annotations, validation, etc.

You are observing the second type of instrumentation (a runtime generated sub-class), which is the default for concrete classes. . . (AspectJ can be used in more complex situations, such as providing dependency injection on classes outside of the Spring container).

Comment: Great explanation, How to overcome this and get only the declared methods?

Comment: Just write a unit test case that uses the class outside of Spring.